# confusionMatrix in R showing 1 prediction out of 27000?

Tags: r, prediction, confusion-matrix

I'm fairly new to R and am trying to build a confusion matrix for xgboost model predictions. However when I call the `confusionMatrix()` it only seems to have one value.

Here are the lengths of my predictions and ground truth labels:

```
> length(y_true)
[1] 27824

> length(xgpreds)
[1] 27824
```

Here is a print of my confusion matrix which seems to show only one prediction in total:

```
> confusionMatrix(xgpreds, y_true)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0    0
[2,]    0    1
```

Can anyone help to understand why this is behaving like this?

Many Thanks.

EDIT with table I get the following:

```
       y_true
xgpreds     0     1
      0 21470  6354
```

Here is the dput of the data:

```
dput(head(xgpred)):
structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor")

dput(head(y_true)):
structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor")
```

Comment: What if you try `table(xgpreds, y_true)`?

Comment: Make sure `y_true` and `xgpreds` are factors and that you're calling `caret::confusionMatrix`.

Comment: Help others help you: Provide a [mcve]. In particular, please [edit] your question to include the output of the R commands `dput(head(xgpreds))` and `dput(head(y_true))`. Seeing the structure of these objects will help people see what the discrepancy is to provide you with a helpful answer

Comment: @Duck both edits have been made to the post.

Comment: @duckmayr both edits have been made to the post.